.net8 SDK based on CMake does not allow native debugging
I am porting a hugh project from visual studio projects (c,c++,c#) to cmake (c, c++ and c# .NET SDK Style). I get everthing build with some small adjustments after unifying my project generation via cmake. Now I have a problem enabling native debugging when running a c# app (my c++ breakpoint get not hit).
for cmake project generation i used
   set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_EnableUnmanagedDebugging "true")
 

But it does not seems to have any effect (maybe old .net4.X style?)
I added a launchSettings.json too (it was generated in my old csproj).
It looks like:
{
  "profiles": {
    "Editor": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  }
}

But seems to have no effect too. I compared my old projects and the generated one and I don't see any large differences. In my vs solution I just set "enable native debugging" in Projects Property -> Debug view (which basically sets the value in launchSettings.json)
My last try was to add launch.vs.json but tells my that my debugger was configured to .NET Framework and not for .NET Core.
Does have anyone an idea how to enable it?
